# Strange behavior when printing float value

Tags: c

Тhese are my calculations

```
float c = 5.0 * (12.0 - 32.0) / 9.0;
printf("%f.2", c);
```

Result is -11.111111.2 but I expected to be -11.11. What is wrong ?

Comment: on the side: %.2f is truncating the result 9.9999 will be shown as 9.99

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format specifier should read `"%.2f"`.

In what you have right now, the `.2` is misplaced. This is why you get more digits than expected, and why the `.2` appears verbatim at the end of the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%f.2", c);
```

should be changed to

```
printf("%.2f", c);
```

The update code is as follows:

```
$ cat f.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float c = 5.0 * (12.0 - 32.0) / 9.0;
    printf("%.2f \n", c);

    return 0;
}
$ gcc f.c 
$ ./a.out 
-11.11 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Format specification of float; as it is incorrect
Instead of using

```
printf("%f.2", c);
```

try using this:

```
float c = 5.0 * (12.0 - 32.0) / 9.0;
printf("%1.2f", c);
```

this should work! :)